# IntelliJ and Play framework: " `scala-library` has broken sources path"

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, playframework

I am having an issue where Scala libraries cannot be resolved in IntelliJ due to a missing `scala-library-src.jar` file under my `SCALA_HOME/lib`.

Under my `Project Structure` > `Project Settings` > `Libraries` > `scala-library` I have the following error:

```
Library 'scala-library' has broken sources path:
/home/lucas/Applications/scala-2.11.2/lib/scala-library-src.jar
```

Where my `SCALA_HOME = /home/lucas/Applications/scala-2.11.2/`. The error makes sense because I do not have the `scala-library-src.jar` under `/home/lucas/Applications/scala-2.11.2/lib/`, although I seem to have the rest of the Scala library:

```
[lucas]/home/.../Applications$ ls scala-2.11.2/lib/
akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar              scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar
ant                                    scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.2-1.0.2.jar
config-1.2.1.jar                       scala-library.jar
forkjoin.jar.desired.sha1              scalap-2.11.2.jar
jline-2.12.jar                         scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.2.jar
scala-actors-2.11.0.jar                scala-reflect.jar
scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar  scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar
scala-compiler.jar                     scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar
[lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../Applications$
```

Where can I find a proper Scala library, or an appropriate `scala-library-src.jar` that would work for me? I downloaded Scala from [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.2.html).

**Background**
I am following [this Play Framework tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_YYgl65FLs), and I hit the error around time 30:10 while using the file `routes.java` under `target > scala-2.11 > src_managed > main > controllers > routes.java`:

```
// @SOURCE:/home/lucas/Dropbox/projects/mapApp/foobar/conf/routes
// @HASH:85b050b64020786e36ab0f298ee833d94c0ac5cf
// @DATE:Wed Oct 15 18:47:03 PDT 2014

package controllers;

public class routes {
public static final controllers.ReverseAssets Assets = new controllers.ReverseAssets();
public static final controllers.ReverseApplication Application = new controllers.ReverseApplication();

public static class javascript {
public static final controllers.javascript.ReverseAssets Assets = new controllers.javascript.ReverseAssets();
public static final controllers.javascript.ReverseApplication Application = new controllers.javascript.ReverseApplication();
}


public static class ref {
public static final controllers.ref.ReverseAssets Assets = new controllers.ref.ReverseAssets();
public static final controllers.ref.ReverseApplication Application = new controllers.ref.ReverseApplication();
}

}
```

Everything after `controllers` or `controllers.javascript` or `controllers.ref` is an unresolved symbol.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest place to find library, sources and javadocs is [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang|scala-library|2.11.2|jar) in my opinion.

---

If you use the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin, you can make sbt generate your project files, and that will automatically include a full Scala facet with sources and docs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I have no more warnings in my project structure after deleting `.idea` and running `sbt gen-idea`. I still have compilation errors in my `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java` file, might you have any suggestions? For example, I have an errors like `Cannot resolve symbol ReverseAssets` in the `routes.java` file shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If you run activator in your project, type clean and then compile.